# Angle between planes algorithm is too slow

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, graph-theory

I have written working code calculating the angle between the adjacent planes.

Here's what I already tried to optimise:

1) I got rid of couple of np built-in functions, e.g. np.cross() and np.linalg.norm(), that gave me a couple of seconds.

2) It was for z in range(1, n), I changed 1 to k in order to not take into account already calculated triangles.

I also tried to make faster input, but to no avail.

Please, can someone tell me how to make it significantly faster?
I'm not well-acquainted with graphs, and I have a bad feeling about this...

(Migrated to Code Review)

Comment: If the code is complete and works, but just needs improvement, it should really be on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thank you, I'll add it there.

Answer (score 1):

You determine the adjacency of the triangles by matching all triangles to each other. If you create a dictionary of edges, you can find adjacent triangles more efficiently.

Use the two nodes of an edge as key. In order to make the key unique, make the node with the lowest index the first one. You can create the dict when you read the indices:

```
edge = {}

for i in range(n):
    a, b, c = [int(j) for j in raw_input().split()]
    ind.append((a, b, c))

    k = (min(a, b), max(a, b))
    edge[k] = edge.get(k, []) + [i]

    k = (min(b, c), max(b, c))
    edge[k] = edge.get(k, []) + [i]

    k = (min(c, a), max(c, a))
    edge[k] = edge.get(k, []) + [i]
```

Use the dict like so:

```
def calculate_angle():
    for e in edge:
        if len(e) == 2:
            i1, i2 = e
            n1 = norm[i1]
            n2 = norm[i2]

            a = abs(math.acos(max(-1, min(1, dot(n1, n2)))))
            angles_list.append(a)

    return max(angles_list)
```

The drawback here is that the angles appear in an arbitrary order in the list, but that's what happens in your original code, too.

You can speed up the program by precalculating the normal as unit vector for each tria only once and store it in the list `norm`. That's what I have done above. The angle calculation is then only the arc cosine of the dot product.

And do you only need the maximum value? Then don't create a list, but keep a running maximum which you update if the current angle is greater than the current maximum.

Comment: @M Oehm, thank you very much for detailed answer.
But I still have a couple of questions:  `i1, i2 = e` - here we get 2 arbitrary values?
I precaculate normals thusly: 
`norm= []
def normals(triangles):
    for t in triangles:
        a = angle_norm(t)
        norm.append(unit_vector(a))
    return norm`
but get IndexError: list index out of range in the line  `n1 = norm[i1]` , don't get, why.

Comment: @ M Oehm, and one last question: when I print the edge, I get:
{(0, 1): [0], (1, 2): [0, 1], (1, 3): [1], (2, 3): [1], (0, 2): [0]}
I really fail to understand why these key-value pairs look like this.
What does it mean, exactly? That value of key (1,2) is [0,1], for instance.

Comment: The way you precalculate the normals looks okay, but since you modify a global list, there's no need to return the list. How do you call `normals`? The key values for the edges are tuples. Usually strings or integers are uses as dict keys, but Python allows any hashable type. `edge[(1, 2)] == [0, 1]` means that the dge between nodes 1 and 2 belongs to the two triangles 0 and 1. The edge between nodes 0 and 1 has only one triangle, 0, attached. It is a border edge.

Comment: @M Oehm, understood about key-valur pairs, thank you:)
I tried to fix the bug, now it doesn't like my effort to call int by index.
I call normals() inside calculate_angle(): https://repl.it/Hk9J

Comment: Two things: Pre-calculating the normals means that you calculate them once and store them so that you don't have to do the (possibly costly) calculation every time you need it. Move the call to `normals()` before the call to `calculate_angle()`. And in normals, you call `angle_norm(i)` with an integer, where you need an list of nodes. Use `for i in ind:` here instead of `for i in range(n):`.

Comment: @M Oehm, I changed foreach to for in vain tries to get rid of the` list index out of range.` I change it back and here we go: https://repl.it/Hk9J/2
Maybe it's because there are only 5 edges, but 6 indices in ind ?

Comment: Looks good to me. The numbers in the value lists of `edge` can only be valid triangle indices. Is your data 1-based, i.e. are your triangle indoces from 1 to `n`? The code uses Python indices from 0 to `n - 1`.

Comment: @M Oehm, my indices start from 0, that's ok.

Comment: I've run your code with the  Utah teapot and got no errors. Could you check whether the read indices are in the valid range whan you read them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143632/discussion-between-thedoctor-and-m-oehm).

Comment: Okay, I'm silly. `for e in edge:` iterates over the keys, which are nodes. It must iterate over the values, so `for e in edge.values():` or `foe x,e in edge.items():` or `for x in edge: e = edge[x]` or some such.